# Why does my NSUserActivity not show up in the Shortcuts app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I've defined 3 different `NSUserActivity`s in my iOS app to allow shortcuts to launch my app in different views. These worked just fine.

For example:

```
userActivityGo = [[NSUserActivity alloc] initWithActivityType:SIRI_MAIN_ACTIVITY_ID];
userActivityGo.title = @"Launch App";
userActivityGo.eligibleForPrediction = YES;
userActivityGo.eligibleForSearch = YES;
userActivityGo.userInfo = @{@"action" : @"go"};
userActivityGo.requiredUserInfoKeys = [NSSet setWithArray:userActivityGo.userInfo.allKeys];
self.userActivity = userActivityGo;
```

Recently (maybe due to iOS recent updates?) I've noticed these shortcuts are missing from the Shortcuts app.

When I enter the "apps" section in Shortcuts, my app is not listed there, but I can still see my predefined shortcuts and see them under "Siri Suggestions".

I did not implement intents since I don't have any special UI or input I need from the user, but as I've already said - it worked before.

Were there any related changes that could cause this?